# Cross Site Scripting (XSS) between facebook.com and m.facebook.com?

Tags: facebook

I'm developing facebook app on platforms: facebook canvas and website (to make it work on mobiles). The problem is that when I'm trying to click on my test app from m.facebook.com website in console i see error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://www.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fm.facebook.com%2Fapps%2F…
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://m.facebook.com/' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

And on screen inside facebook body: "No internet connection. Try again." When I click on "Try again" link situation repeats. But when I'm refreshing whole page application opens on web platform as it's supposed to.

Error shows before my app is called so I doubt it's my sdk configuration error.

I'll add that when I'm opening my app from android facebook application or from facebook.com website problem don't occur.

It looks like XSS between facebook.com and m.facebook.com websites. Anyone meet similar issue? Any ideas if I can solve it? I wrote report to facebook and waiting for answer from them as I'm not sure if it's my error or issue lies at their side.

Thx in advance for help.

Comment: What exactly does _“when I'm trying to click on my test app from m.facebook.com website”_ mean – what are you clicking on and where?

Comment: I go to last tab on m.facebook.com (bookmarks), where are listed favorites, applications and so on. And there is my app listed too. When I'm clicking it, error shows.

Comment: I'd add printscreen's but I have too low rep

Comment: It seems this is a general bug with Facebook, and not related to your app. I will make sure we follow up on this. Thanks for reporting.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)